# Google Facebook and email Auth in android app with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android app using Firebase and I want to add 3 Login option: Facebook, Google and email (and password).

I want to give the user 3 options when he wants to login: sign in with email and password or login with Facebook or Google.
If the user chooses Facebook or Google, I want to check if the email of the Facebook/Google belongs to another credential, and if it is, I want to link the user with the new credential. Else, sign-in in the normal way.

For example, let's assume that I have Facebook and Google accounts with the same email, and I have already signed-in through email and password auth. When I will click the Facebook login button, the app will notice that my email belongs to existing user and will connect my facebook account to my existing user (probably with `user.linkWithCredential()`). The same if I tries to sign-in via Google, or if I create new user using email and password if he already logged-in via Google...

I have tried to do something like this, but I still not sure how to get the other credential (without asking the user to sign-in from different provider) or the firebase existing user, in order to link it with the new credential.

```
authResultTask = mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
            loggedIn(LoginType.FACEBOOK);
        } else {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                mAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail(email /*not sure how to get the email also*/).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult().getProviders().contains(
                                    GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {

                                mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                // Link initial credential to existing account.
                                                        getExistingUser()/*somehow get the existing user*/.linkWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    makeToast(R.string.error_occurred);
                                                    disable.enableAndRemoveProgress();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        } else {
                            makeToast(R.string.error_occurred);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                makeToast(R.string.error_occurred);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Do you have any idea how it can be done?

Comment: may be more genl than you need ... have you checked into this lib?
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android